# How to install Wesnoth game from a tar.bz2?

Tags: installation, games

I'm trying to install [wesnoth.org](http://www.wesnoth.org/) game on Ubuntu. I have saved the file to my machine but don't know what to do now since it is in a `tar.bz2` format.

Answer (score 2):

If you using Maverick or lower [WesnothBinariesLinux](http://wiki.wesnoth.org/WesnothBinariesLinux#Maverick)

Else [Compiling](http://wiki.wesnoth.org/WesnothBinariesLinux#Compiling_2)

Comment: The first priority is to find the program in the Software Centre. If it is there, you can easily install.

Answer (score 2):

Typing,

```
sudo apt-get install wesnoth-1.8
```

at the terminal will install Wesnoth. As user4124 suggested in the comment below, the best option is to find it through the Software Center. Plus it's very easy that way.

Comment: The pacakge `wesnoth-1.8` is better, as it includes the campaigns etc. The core package is just the core without the single player game play.

Comment: You can also find debian/ubuntu packages on http://getdeb.net and http://playdeb.net. Using packages is the easiest choice by far.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you downloaded the source of The Battle for Wesnoth and you prefer it to [the already packaged versions for Ubuntu](http://wiki.wesnoth.org/WesnothBinariesLinux#Ubuntu). The source needs to be compiled to create executables, so you need to compile it before you can install it. To compile and install it you can follow [these instructions](http://wiki.wesnoth.org/WesnothBinariesLinux#Compiling_2) which are copied here for convenience:

> ### Compiling
>
> If you choose to build Wesnoth from source you should add the datadir
>   flag to *configure* to ensure your installation puts the data in the
>   same place as the official installation path:
>
> ```
> cd /usr/src
> tar -xvjf wesnoth-1.x.x.tar.bz2
> cd wesnoth-1.x.x
> ./configure --datadir=/usr/share/games ...
> make
> sudo make install
> ```

See http://wiki.wesnoth.org/CompilingWesnoth for more information.